# As3 - How To Check What IDE the SWF is Running From with Code?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, flash-builder, flash-cs5

I know this is kind of a strange thing to I want to find, but here is a little backstory as to why I'm trying to do this:

I am making an online multiplayer flash game. I am using flash builder and flash professional for writing as3 and working with graphics. I am also running a development server (by playerio in visual studio ultimate). The way I am testing this online multiplayer game is by running the swf once from flash professional and once from flash builder. They are both connected to the exact same action script 3 code and flash movie clips (via a swc file). I like this setup a lot because flash pro and flash builder each have their own little output area, and I can see the debugging output for each user separately.

**The Problem**

Although the two swf's are running the exact same code, I want them to behave differently. For example, the flash pro version gets a reference to the image from:

```
_gameOverPopup = this["gameOverPopup"];
```

and the flash builder user gets it like this:

```
_gameOverPopup = new GameOverPopup;
```

There are many other differences as well. For example, I am automatically authenticating and logging in with a different user in each case by just hardcoding username and password in. So now my code looks something like this:

```
if (inFlashBuilder) {
     // this only happens when debugging in Flash Builder
     authenticateWith("billyboy", "Secret123");
}
else {
     // this only happens when debugging in Flash Professional
     authenticateWith("joeshmoe", "password1");
}
```

This works great, but I am manually changing the *inFlashBuilder* variable in my code. I basically just have it at the top of the class:

```
private var inFlashBuilder:Boolean = true;
```

and **I have to manually changing it from true to false each time before I compile**. Oh man, I wish there were a method in System or something like that which I could use control this flag variable. If only...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll want to use compiler constants.  FlashPro actually already sets one in regards to the IDE.  You can access it as follows in AS3 (it will produce true or false):

```
CONFIG::FLASH_AUTHORING
```

So, you would want to do this:

```
if (CONFIG::FLASH_AUTHORING) {
     // this only happens when debugging in Flash Professional
     authenticateWith("joeshmoe", "password1");
}
else {
     // this only happens when debugging in Flash Builder
     authenticateWith("billyboy", "Secret123");
}
```

You'll want to set up the same constant in Flash builder but set the value to false.
In the **flex-config.xml**, add this:

```
<compiler> 
    <define append="true"> 
        <name>CONFIG::FLASH_AUTHORING</name> 
        <value>false</value> 
    </define>
</compiler>
```

See this link to find out more about how to do this in flash builder:
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf69084-7abd.html

Comment: Thanks, this works! Although I'm not using flex in flash builder so I added the config constant just by going to Project -> Properties -> Actionscript Compiler -> Actionscript compiler arguments and entering this:               -define=CONFIG::IN_FLASH_AUTHORING,false

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to build it twice, you can also have a post-build hook that copies the swf under a different name. Then, in your code, you can check `this.loaderInfo.loaderURL` and differentiate your logic that way.

```
if( this.loaderInfo.loaderURL.indexOf( "second.swf" ) )
    // do alt logic
```